# C - Malloc or calloc...and how?

Tags: c

i have a text file where the first number defines the size of the arrays. I know that `calloc` or `malloc` can reserve memory, but how?

this code:

```
typedef struct alpha {
    int* size;
    char name;
    int  tot;
    char line[60];
} ALPHA;

fgets(line, 60, fp);
tot = atoi(line);
size = (int*)calloc(name, sizeof(int);
```

Imagine that in the first line of text is the number 10, with this code the size of name will be 10? like name[10]???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALPHA *alphas1 = calloc(tot, sizeof(*alphas1));
ALPHA *alphas2 = malloc(tot * sizeof(*alphas2));
```

is a slightly better version of:

```
ALPHA* alphas1 = calloc(tot, sizeof(ALPHA));
ALPHA* alphas2 = malloc(tot * sizeof(ALPHA));
```

Now you can access alphas1 and so on, "array-like":

```
alphas1[0], alphas1[1], alphas1[2], ..., alphas1[tot] 
alphas2[0], alphas2[1], alphas2[2], ..., alphas2[tot]
```

`alphas1[...]` is of type `ALPHA`
`alphas2[...]` is of type `ALPHA` .

PS: To make your code more reliable, don't forget to check if a malloc / calloc failed. To this verify that (in your case) check if `alphas1` or `alphas2` are different from `NULL`. In case they are `NULL`, you won't be able to access them as presented, and you should design a mechanism to recover from this, or simply exit the program (+error message).

Answer (score 3):

Use one of the following:

```
ALPHA* alphas1 = calloc(tot, sizeof(ALPHA));
// or
ALPHA* alphas2 = malloc(tot * sizeof(ALPHA));
```

Those allocate memory for `tot` of your `ALPHA` structures.

Comment: You might need to cast the return value to (ALPHA *) to avoid compiler warnings.

Comment: The question is tagged C. I would be annoyed by a C compiler that gives me a warning for THIS.

Comment: @Tyler, the only reason to cast the return value of malloc() / calloc() is to be compatible with C++.

Comment: @Tyler that's only needed in C++, in C it's recommended not to cast, as it makes the code less readable, and prone to errors.

Answer (score 3):

There's several problems with your code.

First, you seem to be confusing a declaration of what a data type is with actually having a variable.  You declare a `struct`, and from then on it's a data type, much like `int` or `double`.  Before you assign anything to one, you need to have one.  You can get one either by defining one in the function (`ALPHA a;`) or by allocating memory for one with `malloc()` or `calloc()`.

To use `calloc()`, you have two arguments, one being how many whatevers you want, and one being the size of a whatever.  For `malloc()`, you multiply the two.  The other difference is that `malloc()` returns memory with whatever used to be in it, while `calloc()` initializes everything to zero.  (That's zero-length string or integral zeros according to the Standard.  Other values are not guaranteed, but with most modern systems you'll get the equivalent of a zero.)  These functions return a pointer to the memory allocated.

You seem to want `tot` `int`s, so (using `calloc()`), the correct statement is something like `int * a = calloc(tot, sizeof(int));`, or `int * a = calloc(tot, sizeof(*a));`.  No cast is required in C (it is required in C++, but you usually wouldn't use `malloc()` or `calloc()` in C++), and the only thing it can do is cover up a possible mistake (leaving out `#include <stdlib.h>` to be specific).

Once you have that, you can refer to the `int`s as something like `a[3]`.

Putting the result in a field of an `ALPHA` is doable, but you really do need an `ALPHA`, so something like

```
ALPHA a;
a.size = calloc(tot, sizeof(*a));
```

will work.  You would therefore refer to it as `a.size[3]`, for example.

Also, I don't see what `name` is doing.  It's one character, which is not enough for any non-empty string, and I don't know why you've got it in the `calloc()` call.  You might want `name` to be a dynamically allocated string, with `size` being its size.  In that case, you'd need to change the lines in the declaration of `ALPHA` to be

```
int size;
char * name;
```

and the code might be be

```
ALPHA a;
fgets(line, 60, fp);
a.size = atoi(line);
a.name = calloc(a.size, sizeof(*a.name));
```

Once you've done that, after entering 10, you can refer to `a.name[0]` through `a.name[9]`, and that's your ten characters.  `a.name[10]` would be one past the end.  Note that you can only put a nine-character string in a ten-character array, since you need to have room for the null terminator (the `'\0'` which is the last character of any C-style string).  If you want to be able to enter the specified number of characters, you'd want to add 1 to `a.size` after putting the user-entered number in.

Answer (score 1):

You might just want to

ALPHA alphas[tot];

Comment: I think his assignment requires the use of dynamic allocation.

Comment: Not to mention that should be `struct alpha alphas[tot];` or `ALPHA alphas[tot];`.

Comment: yup my bad - changed to ALPHA
also, this is dynamic allocation -- just on the stack instead of the heap, just like if I had used alloca